# How to pack fields in a struct on Xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm trying to pack fields into a union-style struct on Xamarin iOS.
Code like the below works on the simulator but crashes on-device. My guess is that it either has to do with memory alignment, or else FieldOffsets are unsupported on-device, which would be sad.

The struct looks like this, and I'm running on 64-bit ARM.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public struct Union
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds an arbitrary reference, and can't share space with value types.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public object RefValue;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public bool BoolValue;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public double NumericValue;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    // We're assuming DateTime has a size of 8 bytes
    // but this may a bit risky, according to Google. 
    public DateTime DateTime; 

    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public UnionType Type;
}
```

where `UnionType` is an enum that derives from `byte` indicates which of the fields is the correct one:

```
public enum UnionType : byte
{
    None = 0, // uninitialized
    Reference,
    Bool,
    Number,
    DateTime,
}
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: What compiler options are you using?  The compiler create a memory size for you object and when the micro access an address outside the memory then you get an exception.  It looks like you structure is 17 bytes.  Your Pack size should match the micro size.  If you have a 64 bit micro and it tried to write to UnionType it would write 8 bytes (7 bytes after the structure ended) while the memory allocated would only be 17 bytes.

Comment: "crashes on-device" - is there an exception causing the crash?  Have you tried to catch it?